# Determine the maximum password age in Active Directory

Tags: .net, active-directory, passwords, lastpasswordset

I want to expire users' passwords on an individual basis in Microsoft Active directory at different times.

I understand that each user within AD does not have it's own password expry time. Instead there is a `Maximum Password Age` associated with the domain, and a `LastPasswordSet` date associated with the user.

I intend to set the `LastPasswordSet` to simulate the behavior of each user having an individual max password age.

In order to do this, I need to know the `Maximum Password Age` associated with the domain. How to I determine this programmatically from .NET?

**Edit: I see that `LastPasswordSet` is readonly, so my approach may have no merit.**

Comment: http://en.csharp-online.net/User_Management_with_Active_Directory%E2%80%94How_Password_Modification_Dates_Are_Stored may be of use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ADSI it's the property `maxPwdAge`. Here's an article that includes a sample of getting this out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974598.aspx