# How to access Maximum Password Age property in Active Directory, programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

We're trying to implement a Password Expiration handling mechanism in a ASP.NET MVC app using Active Directory for authorization, and we need access to Maximum Password Age value to provide a correct expiration period. However, we've not been able to access the value/property via these instructions (or similar approaches), using the DirectoryEntry API:

[How can I get 'minimum password age' of user in active directory using asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403711/how-can-i-get-minimum-password-age-of-user-in-active-directory-using-asp-net)

[Determine the maximum password age in Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904806/determine-the-maximum-password-age-in-active-directory)

In each case we simply get a `NULL` value for property `maxPwdAge`. We also query for `MaxPwdAge`, `MaxPasswordAge`, and `MaximumPasswordAge` (some sources suggested different property names). We also searched against different domain objects, namely the root container and the Users container to no avail.

Is there any way to find the Maximum Password Age programmatically using the DirectoryEntry API. Or alternatively, the PrincipalContext API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, AD allows fine grained password policies. This means that max age can vary by user depending upon the configuration of the directory. Further, there are a couple of ways to configure this (using the newer FGPP mechanism or the older per-domain policy mechanism).

Brian's advice from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100121/active-directory-account-password-expiration-date-with-fine-grain-password-polic) should get you going.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of it. However, the problem is actually accessing the Password Policy settings, and being able to react, not configuring them. Being able to read these settings and support that behavior in the app is the goal.

Comment: Do you not have access? You should be able to read the specified attrs...can you try outside of your code using the same security context (ie with ldp or a similar tool)?

Comment: We've tried that, but the actual properties aren't there using tools like ADSI.

Comment: Repro code? Or steps you followed (*exactly*) in ldp? With exact attribute names? Thx.

Comment: I've search for the properties I posted in the question, specifically `maxPwdAge` and the instructions [here](http://en.csharp-online.net/User_Management_with_Active_Directory—Determining_Domain-Wide_Account_Policies).